# Can a desktop app update your websites database?

Tags: database, desktop-application

This is a hypothetical question that I don't seem to be able to find an answer to. In theory, could you write a `desktop program` which allows you to alter the `database` of a `personal website`? A simple example would be a `blog`, where instead of having to go online and log into Admin section of your website, you would have a `desktop app` where you could write a blog offline and once you have internet it would automatically update your website?

Would this theoretically be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  However, probably not recommended as you would have to allow direct connections to your database through the firewall unless your desktop application made the same http/https pots that the website does when updating the database.  At that point, you're just creating a new UI that calls the old UI to do the same actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows you could use the free tool [Microsoft Live Writer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8621) for that. I am sure you can find other free tools for other OS out there.

There is not also an Open Source version of it [Open Live Writer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingOpenLiveWriterAnOpenSourceForkOfWindowsLiveWriter.aspx)